# How to Set the Open GLES2.0 to work with the Android Camera?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

In My Android Camera Application i want to Set some Effect on the Android Camera Preview witht the Help of OPEN GL vertex shader and fragment shader.

Is there any example or source code to use the Android camera with Open GLES effect ? ?

I have seen [this](http://nhenze.net/?p=172). But I want android camera effect in Only One SurfaceView not on another.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar. But the code is quite messy, it was just a prototype. Check it on my github https://github.com/Jaa-c/PDA-Lupa/tree/master/src/pda/lupa. Preview from the camera is displayed via OpenGL in MyGLSurfaceView, but only in greyscale, because it's to slow to convert colors. But it doesn't use shaders, since it was using only ES 1.1.

Than there is one of my answers on similar topic here: [Apply custom filters to camera output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371055/apply-custom-filters-to-camera-output/8372731#8372731). It descibes some possible ways to manually display camera preview in android.