# Android camera preview processing

Tags: android, performance, filter, camera, preview

I know that there are already similar questions, but they don't help me.

Currently, I'm playing around with the camera preview and I'd like to apply some custom filters. However, the performance is really bad. I found many approaches, but nothing worked.

- [This method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371055/apply-custom-filters-to-camera-output) works, but as the answer mentions, the performance is really bad
- I've changed the above conversion of YUV to RGB with the method in [this post](http://www.41post.com/3470/programming/android-retrieving-the-camera-preview-as-a-pixel-array), but the result is the same. The performance is bad.
- I've also tried the [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) examples in the Play store, but the performance wasn't as good as I hoped. Additionally you have the increased complexity with the NDK.

So what is the best approach to apply a filter? I know that it is possible as many other apps provide good quality and performance, e.g. [Camera MX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magix.camera_mx&feature=search_result) and [Cartoon Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fingersoft.cartooncamera&feature=search_result). How did they do it?

Thanks for your tips.

Comment: What kind of filtering do you plan to do? I personally am using OpenCV in native, and the performances are really good for simple filters. Moreover, if you only need some simple filters, you can even use OpenCV in Java. Could you be more explicit about the "bad performances" you get with OpenCV?