# How to apply different live effects to android Camera?

Tags: android

I want to develop a **[Camera 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dama.camera2&hl=en)** kind of application. So i just wanted to know how to apply live effects to android Camera .Is there any android library for that? plz help me to solve the issue.

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? I assume by live effects you mean shown on the preview.

You can try what the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371055/apply-custom-filters-to-camera-output) suggested, but any sort of complicated filter implemented in java is going to slow things down. For good performance you'll probably have to write some native code to process the previews. The good news is, if you're writing NDK code you can make use of libraries like [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) to do the filtering for you.