# How to change camera brightness when camra is on open mode in android..?

Tags: android, camera, brightness

Now i am working in Business Card reader application, in that i want to change the camera image **brightness** when camera is on open mode/camera is on. please tell me what camera **parameter need to set**.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want apply brightness change when default camera opens or in your app..

Comment: I want to change camera brightness by using my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targeting API Level 8 and higher, you could look at the camera [parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html), specifically at [white balance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setWhiteBalance%28java.lang.String%29) and [exposure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setExposureCompensation%28int%29). You should play a bit with them to find the correct settings for your needs.

Comment: @fastque, i use parameters.setExposureCompensation(int value) method, but please tell me what value(s) is to set as a parameter. i used values as parameters.getMaxExposureCompensation() is it correct..?

Comment: You should test values based on your needs, I cannot tell you because you didn't mention in which way you would like to change the brightness. Application should call getMinExposureCompensation and getMaxExposureCompensation to know if exposure compensation is supported and then set a value. What kind of results are you getting? Did you try to change the white balance?

Comment: @fasteque  can u pls help me how can i apply effects on live camera android using custom camera like vintage effect

Comment: @ErumHannan check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174969/how-to-apply-different-live-effects-to-android-camera, both suggested answers and OpenCV library. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

white balance is not supported for all devices. that means white balance value is auto.so we can't increase or decrease that value.

All devices supporting the exposure. The default value of the exposure is 0.

and we are able to get the maximum and minimum values from the camera api like this

```
 public void setExposureCompensation(int value){

    Camera.Parameters camParams = mCamera.getParameters();

    int minExpCom=camParams.getMinExposureCompensation();
    int maxExpCom=camParams.getMaxExposureCompensation();

    //Log.i(TAG,"minExpCom : "+minExpCom);
    //Log.i(TAG,"maxExpCom : "+maxExpCom);
    if(maxExpCom>0 && value<=maxExpCom && value>=minExpCom){
        camParams.setExposureCompensation(value);
        mCamera.setParameters(camParams);

    }

 }
```

we manipulate the values of exposure in between the min and max of exposure.

This is the only option supporting all the devices For controlling the brightness of camera.

Answer (score 0):

You can see my code to change camera Exposure value:

```
// set Camera Exposure value from input progress (0.0f - 1.0f)
void setEV(float progress) {
    if (progress < 0.0f && progress > 1.0f) return;
    params = mCamera.getParameters();
    int min = params.getMinExposureCompensation(); // -3 on my phone
    int max = params.getMaxExposureCompensation(); // 3 on my phone
    float realProgress = progress - 0.5f;
    int value;
    if (realProgress < 0) {
        value = -(int) (realProgress * 2 * min);
    } else {
        value = (int) (realProgress * 2 * max);
    }
    // if changed
    if (value != params.getExposureCompensation()) {
        params.setExposureCompensation(value);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }
}
```