# How can I make this more efficient in Android?

Tags: android

I have this piece of code that takes the bitmap of a `CameraPreview` from a `TextureView` and renders it on a `ImageView`.

```
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    // Invoked every time there's a new Camera preview frame

    bmp = mTextureView.getBitmap();
    bmp2 = bmp.copy(bmp.getConfig(),true);

    for(int x=0;x<bmp.getWidth();x++){
        for(int y=0;y<bmp.getHeight();y++){
            //Log.i("Pixel RGB (Int)", Integer.toString(bmp.getPixel(x,y)));
            if(bmp.getPixel(x,y) < -8388608){
                bmp2.setPixel(x,y,Color.WHITE);
            }else{
                bmp2.setPixel(x,y,Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
    }

    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp2);
}
```

So basically I will be applying real-time image-processing on whatever the camera shows. For now it just back and whites pixels. It is a bit slow now, and the bitmap has only a width and height of ~250 pixels.

Is this the recommended way of doing this ?

Comment: Indeed you are going through every pixels one at a time. I can only point to an interesting post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8372731/603270

Comment: Please edit your post and add more tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To filter bitmaps efficiently you can use ColorMatrixColorFilter. For example to make your image black & white use this code:

```
ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
colorMatrix.setSaturation(0);

float m = 255f;
float t = -255*1.2f;
ColorMatrix threshold = new ColorMatrix(new float[] {
            m, 0, 0, 1, t,
            0, m, 0, 1, t,
            0, 0, m, 1, t,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0
});

// Convert to grayscale, then scale and clamp
colorMatrix.postConcat(threshold);

ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
imageView.setColorFilter(filter);
```

Basically you have to transform the color range so values equal to (color) and (color+1) are (0) and (1). That's why I'm multiplying color by 255 and shifting. You may want to play with these parameters to get the right result.

Check out the slides here: http://chiuki.github.io/android-shaders-filters/#/16

Comment: Cool I tried it an it is much faster. I was wondering if the same approach can be applied for applying other things, not only changing color, like a Gaussian filter for example, where you will need the values of nearby pixels

Comment: The fastest way to perform a gaussian blur is to use RenderScript. For an example check out this code: https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/shadow/ShadowGenerator.java#L71

Comment: I ended up using renderscript.