# Apply black and white opengl filter on Camera2 api

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, android-camera2

I am new to both camera2 and openGLES. I want to apply a shader over camera preview obtained by camera2 api which can convert preview in black and white. I believe grey scale filter is what will help here. Can anyone suggest any demo application which i can refer to for this requirement ?

Comment: May [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371055/apply-custom-filters-to-camera-output) can help you.